# Finding out all about Android Uri class - use and purpose

Tags: android, uri

Does anyone have some helpful links to find out about Android Uri's?

For example, you get a Uri back from a "take a picture" Intent.   What does a URI look like and how do you use it.  Why are they used instead of filenames or file handles?

The Dev documentation on the Uri class is practically worthless.  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html   It is only clear if you already know exactly what it is, and how to use it.

Thanks for any links.

Comment: good question. I was having problems with this. It seems a little silly to name this class URI as that is typically used for HTTP related stuff

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'd check out the content providers section

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html

It expalins URI's for the different content providers and how they work.

Answer (score 3):

Read this post it explained what is URI and URL ? Hope it will help to you.http://javapapers.com/servlet/uri-and-url-difference/

This is a list of URIs that can be used in intents.
http://www.openintents.org/en/uris